# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tqdm.notebook'

Tags: python, tqdm

I have to import `tqdm` using the following import command, but when I do I get an error.

**Code**

```
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
```

**Error**

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-70-e86f188036ca> in <module>
----> 1 from tqdm.notebook import tqdm

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tqdm.notebook'
```

`tqdm` is already installed in my environment but still I face this issue. How to fix this?

Comment: which version of tqdm you have?

Comment: Can you run `python -m pip list` ?

Comment: I have ''4.31.1" version of tqdm @404pio

Comment: Yes I have run `python -m pip list` and it shows `tqdm` is present @kinshukdua

Comment: Are you *absolutely* certain the CLI and Notebook are running in (pointing to) the same environment?

Comment: I am not very clear about it @S3DEV

Comment: Try to call `!pip freeze | grep tqdm` in jupyter. Can you also just import tqdm - is it ok?

Comment: Please do **not** update your post with follow-up questions after an answer has resolved your issue. Open a new question instead (edited).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to upgrade your `tqdm` packgage may be it is not containing that package

```
pip install tqdm --upgrade
```

or

```
pip install tqdm -U
```

Comment: Using this the import works but when I implement it I get an error `ImportError: IProgress not found. Please update jupyter and ipywidgets.`

Comment: Have you restart Jupyter notebook after upgrade?? or try `pip3 install ipywidgets --user

`

Comment: I restarted the kernel and I get another error `TypeError: string indices must be integers`. I am adding the Model Training code in the question where I am using `tqdm`.

Comment: I guess you can update the post with code so it will be better to understand!

Comment: `tqdm` error is resolved but can you help with this error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232288/discussion-between-bhavya-parikh-and-ishan-dutta).